# Livescript: AudioContext can't get defined

Tags: javascript, livescript, webkitaudiocontext, audiocontext

I'm trying to load audio with XMLHttpRequests and AudioContext, my code looks like this:

```
class AudioExample
    audioContext: null
    init: ->
        AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext
        @audioContext = new AudioContext!
        # r = xmlhttprequest magic
        r.onload = (e) ->
            rr = e.target #XMLHttpRequest{response: ArrayBuffer, song: Object, si: Object}
            @audioContext.decodeAudioData rr.response, (buffer) ->
                # ...
```

The error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'decodeAudioData' of undefined.`

When I console.log the audioContext I get a valid audioContext object, so why is it undefined on code execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with bound functions; you can diagnose it by putting a `console.log @` inside `r.load = (e) -> ...`.

The solution is to bind `r.onload` handler using `~>`:

```
r.onload = (e) ~> ...
```

Check LiveScript docs for [Bound Functions](http://livescript.net/#functions).